# Why do hallucinations appear in depression?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, depression, hallucinations

We all know the stories of people who saw a miracle in the deepist troubles like [gangsters who turned to faith](http://www.chicoer.com/article/ZZ/20100814/NEWS/100819841) - or an older example could be the miracles in jail [in the Bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2012) (Acts: Peter and Paul).

How wide-spread is the phenomenon where people expierence hallucinations in a depressing situation? What is the neurological cause? And what hormones (neurotrasmitters) participate on this phenomenon?

Please concentrate on the neurological point of view, rather than on the psychological aspects.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at The God drug DMT. It causes people to see/talk to God and can be taken as an actual drug, but I believe it is also produced in the body during near death experiences. I am no expert in it but here's wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N,N-Dimethyltryptamine

Comment: Interesting, this actually seems like the thing I was looking for!

Comment: I've experienced this "phenomenon" firsthand. I'll try to get some DMT and tell you if the effects are similar.

Comment: @Andrew - DMT is an illicit drug and its use is not without dangers. 'Trying to get some DMT' may not be so easy :) But admittedly, it is one of the most interesting drugs on this planet. Closely related to LSD and other compounds in the tryptamine class. It is rapidly degraded though and specific methods are often used to ingest sufficient amounts. Look up ayahuasca and a world will open up.